# Unable to run MS Tests V2 tests on Team Build 2015

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild, mstest, tfs-2015

I'm using MS Tests V2 (v 1.0.8-rc2) to be able to use the new DataTestMethod and DataRow attributes in my tests.

I added MS Tests V2 thanks to nuget and it works well on my dev machine.

I don't manage to execute these same tests from a server build.

I have this error :

> ### [error].nuget\Packages\MSTest.TestAdapter.1.1.8-rc2\build\net45\MSTest.TestAdapter.targets(26,10):
>
> Error MSB4184: unable to evaluate expression """.Identity". Méthod
> 'System.String.Identity' is not found.

This error cames from the following line of the .targets :

```
<Link>$(CurrentUICultureHierarchy.Identity)\%(Filename)%(Extension)</Link>
```

Do you have any idea about how to make it works ?

Comment: Have you solved this issue?

Comment: No, I spent about 2 hours on this problem and checked the configuration and did not found a solution. I have removed these useful attributes to come back to the classic version of MS Test and not the pre-release version :(

Answer (score 0):

If it works well on your dev machine and not works fine from a server build. Very likely the environment problem.

To make sure the build successful, you should keep your build server environment the same with your local environment. Please double check this, such as .Net version.

For trouble shooting, you could try to manually run your build and test on your build agent.